# How to set the server to start cron after a long period of inactivity

Tags: .net, triggers, cron, .net-5, quartz.net

My project is made in the .NET5 environment
Example:
I have Quartz.NET schedule set with Cron and task sending emails, everything works in a short time frame.
On the test server, I set a day interval - ultimately it will be weekly.
Additionally, I configured Pools connected to the project with settings.
Unfortunately, the Cron does not start the next day - what else should you pay attention to on the server?

```
q.AddJob<SendEmailQualityControlJob>(opts => opts.WithIdentity(jobKey));
                      
                          // Create a trigger for the job
                          q.AddTrigger(opts => opts
                       
                        .WithIdentity("SendEmailQualityControlJob-trigger").WithCronSchedule("00 00 10 ? * WED ").ForJob(jobKey).StartNow());
```

As per the recommendations below:

https://newbedev.com/quartz-net-scheduler-doesn-t-fire-jobs-triggers-once-deployed

https://www.py4u.net/discuss/1170832

Start Mode: AlwaysRunning
Limit Interval (minutes): 0
Regular Time Interval (minutes): 0

The services were canceled after 50 minutes on the server

2021-09-15 14:24:50.6055||INFO|Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime|Application is shutting down...
2021-09-15 14:24:50.6055||INFO|Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler|Scheduler QuartzScheduler_$*NON_CLUSTERED shutting down.
2021-09-15 14:24:50.6198||INFO|Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler|Scheduler QuartzScheduler*$*NON_CLUSTERED paused.
2021-09-15 14:24:50.6198||INFO|Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler|Scheduler QuartzScheduler*$_NON_CLUSTERED Shutdown complete.
2021-09-15 14:24:50.6346||INFO|AppForSellers.Infrastructure.QuartzNET.Service.SendEmailQualityControlServiceHostService|Usługa SendEmailQualityControlServiceHostService została zatrzymana.
2021-09-15 14:24:50.8126||ERROR|AppForSellers.Infrastructure.QuartzNET.SendEmailQualityControlJob|No Sending Emails System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
at AppForSellers.Infrastructure.QuartzNET.Service.SendEmailQualityControl.ExecuteJobSendEmail(CancellationToken stoppingToken) in C:\Projekty\TLC Spiral Stairs\AppForSellers\Infrastructure\QuartzNET\Service\SendEmailQualityControl.cs:line 158

Comment: Why does services stop after 50 minutes after deploy and
are canceled.?

Comment: Problem is with Pools and recycling in IIS Server. How to set recycling  on Pools?